# IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2549' ('MQRC_CALL_INTERRUPTED')

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using below connectivity network to connect mq from java client.

[image]

Below MQIPT configuration using

```
[global]
CommandPort=1884
RemoteShutDown=true
#MinConnectionThreads=1
#MaxConnectionThreads=300
IdleTimeout=0
ClientAccess=true
QMgrAccess=true
HTTP=true
HTTPChunking=false
Trace=5
ConnectionLog=true
MaxLogFileSize=50
[route]
Name=Route_1
Active=true
ListenerPort=1414
Destination=mq-dmz-************
DestinationPort=********
HTTP=true
HTTPS=true
SSLClient=true
SSLClientProtocols=TLSv1.2
SSLClientKeyRing="path of key ring PFX file"
SSLClientKeyRingPW="path of password file"
HTTPServer=<Http Server name>
HTTPServerPort=443
URIName=<URI name>
SSLClientCAKeyRing="same as SSLClientKeyRing"
SSLClientCAKeyRingPW="same as SSLClientKeyRingPW"
SSLClientCipherSuites=SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
SSLServer=true
SSLServerProtocols=TLSv1.2
SSLServerKeyRing="path of key ring PFX file"
SSLServerKeyRingPW="path of password file"
SSLServerCAKeyRing="same as SSLServerKeyRing"
SSLServerCAKeyRingPW="same as SSLServerCAKeyRing"
SSLServerCipherSuites=SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TCPKeepAlive=true
```

- follwoing issues are coming in both the cases (receive, send).

  ```
  - Connection not continues work 
  - In case of receive it consistently break  after 7 minutes. MQRC connection broken error coming.
  - In case of receive, if queue is empty it will work till 40 minutes, after that it breaks.
  - '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2549' ('MQRC_CALL_INTERRUPTED')
  - compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN') on both case send and receive.
  ```

Below code we are using to connect and get messages

```
MQQueueConnectionFactory factory = getSSLFactory();
            
                mqConnection = createMQConnection(factory);
                mqConnection.start();
                

                logger.info("<<<<<<<<<created queue connection in receive>>>>>>>>>");
                logger.info("After creating connection");
                session = (MQQueueSession) mqConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                Destination destination = session.createQueue(LOCAL_QUEUE_RECEIVE);
                consumer = (MQMessageConsumer) session.createConsumer(destination);
                long messageCount = 0;
                long messageNotReceived = 0;
                consumeMessages(consumer, messageCount, messageNotReceived);
```

consumeMessages method . inside this method i tested with consumer.receive() with timeout also.

```
private void consumeMessages(MQMessageConsumer consumer, long messageCount, long messageNotReceived)
                throws JMSException {
            while (true) {
                JMSMessage message = (JMSMessage) consumer.receiveNoWait();
                TextMessage txt_msg = (TextMessage) message;
                if (message == null) {
                    messageNotReceived++;
                    logger.info("None of the message received. waiting for messages");
                } else {
                    messageCount++;
                    logger.info("Received message:" + txt_msg.getText());

                }
                logger.info("messageNotReceived count : " + messageNotReceived + " messageCount count : "
                        + messageCount);

            }
        }
```

Closing connection in finally block.

I want to consumer should up and running all time. However we will handle network error but currently it failing very frequently.

Please help us . Please guide us where we should investigate this issue, mq client side, client side mqipt, mq server or firewall.

firewall is used between mqipt.

Comment: sometimes connection reset also coming in client side mqipt logs.

Comment: What is the `HBINT` set to on the `SVRCONN` channel? Does the firewall have an idle time out set?  Ensure the `HBINT` is less than any Timeout at the firewall.

Comment: Thanks for input , I will validate the same and get back to you . @JoshMc

Comment: @JoshMc I analyzed that HBINT is less than the timeout of firewall.  Still connection breaking . After analysis TCP dump we found that one of source initiating FIN request to terminate connection.  Can you please suggest

Comment: What was the HBINT vs Timeout of the firewall?  What versions are the IBM MQ classes for JMS jars, MQIPT, the queue manager.

Comment: @JoshMc :  After a long time we did some https port change instead of 443 to something else. That time out issue is resolved. Can you please tell us how we can fix it for 443 port only. I will provide the version detail

Comment: @JoshMc HBINT is 300 seconds at channel level and at firewall it is one hour still this connection break issue is coming.

Comment: What language is the client written in?  What version of MQ are the client MQ libraries from?

Comment: Client Written in java ,  client Version : ibm client jar -9.1.0.5 ,                                    MQ Version is 9.1.0.4                                                                                            
MQIPT version 9.2.0.1 @JoshMc

Comment: Do you only have the time out when you use port 443 for the MQIPT listener or the MQ queue manager listener?   Have you tried setting the HBINT of the SVRCONN a much lower value ( 15 to 30 seconds ).

Comment: While doing hit and try, found out that it's giving issue  on 443 port .  Just changed it and its working fine. From solution perspective we cannot change port on prod.   We will reduce time out  and update you, if any other suggestion you have please update here.